# can't get customToJSON working in sails1 model

Tags: sails.js

Using sails 1.2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I tried adding customToJSON before and after the attributes in model User, but when I serve the user object to a page, password still shows up. When I serve the user object, I don't want password or isSuperAdmin to appear.

Here is the end of my User.js model script:

```
  }, // end attributes
    customToJSON: function() {
      return _.omit(this, ['password', 'isSuperAdmin'])
   },
}; //end module exports
```

I may just be omitting something dumb, but if so please let me know.
thx

Comment: How are you returning the data in your controller? It will be easier to diagnose the problem if we can see the controller.

Comment: aah. good point. If you make an object that omits this attribute you solve the problem. Thanks